# Ultraproducts in the category of structures and elementary embeddings

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

[A previous question on the categorical nature of ultraproducts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11261/is-the-ultraproduct-concept-fundamentally-category-theoretic) had great answers, mostly categorically characterizing ultraproducts in the category of $L$-structures and *homomorphisms* for a fixed signature $L$.  This is understandable, given one of the most important use of ultraproducts is to give a syntax-free characterization of elementary equivalence.

Here I would like to ask sort of its opposite: can one characterize ultraproducts in the category of $L$-structures and *elementary embeddings*?   (This is related to the question of whether or not ultraproducts are a genuinely model-theoretic notion.)

This sounds like what experts of AECs study, but I was not able to find relevant literature.

*Addendum*: Answers focusing on ultra_powers_ are also welcome.  (In fact, that was my original motivation.)

Comment: You seem to claim that genuine model-theoretic notions must be expressible by features of the category of models under elementary embeddings—is that right? To my way of thinking, this would seem to be a rather restricted or even impoverished conception of model theory, not much connected with model theory as practiced by model theorists.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins My point was that being expressible by features of the category of models under elementary embeddings was a sufficient condition.  But I do not necessarily endorse such a view---I rewrote that sentence many times, but it did not come out as properly reflecting my  motivation in my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you asked about ultraproducts, and not ultrapowers, let me argue that the answer must be negative. The reason is that the category of $L$-structures under elementary embeddings is partitioned into disconnected components by the theories of those structures, since elementary embeddings must preserve the theory of the structure and so there can be no morphisms in this category that connect structures with different theories.

But I may form the ultraproduct $\prod M_i/U$ of structures $M_i$ with all different theories, in such a way that the ultraproduct itself had a different theory than each of them. So there will be no morphisms at all that relate any of the $M_i$'s to each other or to the ultraproduct. There will be no diagrams in which the $M_i$'s participate along with the ultraproduct, except diagrams that are disconnected into components in the same way as the category is by the theories of the models. For example, there can be no universal property in this category relating the $M_i$'s to the ultraproduct or to models connected by morphisms to the ultrapower or each other, since there are no morphisms at all relating these structures to any other structures in common—they simply live on different islands. In these circumstances, it seems impossible to find a category-theoretic characterization of the ultraproduct in the category of elementary embeddings.

Comment: And even within a single elementary class, there need be no canonical choice of elementary embedding of any individual $M_i$ into $\prod M_i/U$. (Do you know if we can have all $M_i$s have the same theory but no $M_i$ elementarily embeds into $\prod M_i/U$ at all?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is right, but within any elementary class (an elementary-equivalence equivalence class), any two models have a common elementary extension, so they are in the same component. Indeed, this fact shows that elementary-equivalence is expressible in the category.

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical question, I find it quite interesting, but don't have an example immediately at hand. I would expect that there is such an example. Why not ask a separate question about it?

Comment: [Done!](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450241/can-ultraproducts-avoid-all-factor-structures)

Comment: I was actually interested in ultrapowers, but I (erroneously!) thought that a question on just ultrapowers might be too restrictive.  Should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: Sure, why not? I think you might get some good category-theory answers. One problem I expect will be that the category lacks products.