# What are the logical morphisms from a topos E to Set?

Tags: topos-theory, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

If $E$ is a topos, is there a nice way to characterize the category of logical morphisms $E\to Set$?  Is it complete and/or cocomplete?

The topos $Set$ geometrically represents a point; what does it logically represent?

Comment: I'd be interested if there were any good answers to this. A related question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4044/logical-endofunctors-of-set where even in the case $E = Set$, existence of non-trivial logical endofunctors involve fairly large cardinal hypotheses. 


Comment: What is a logical morphism?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Roughly, a functor $F:A\to B$ between toposes is called "logical" if it preserves finite limits and power-objects. See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor